# Show more than 3 item in a wearable listview without scrolling

Tags: listview, scroll, padding, wear-os, listviewitem

I want to create a wearable listview that can show more than 3 item simultaneously, but the wearable listview only shows 3 item, and i have to scroll down to see the other items. Is this a WearableListView specific thing?

So my WearableListView looks like this:

[image: WearableListView]

But i want to show more than 3 item without scrolling, because it has enough space.

The listview container xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/kaempewatch_screen_bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
    android:id="@+id/exercise_listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The item xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/li_tv_training_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:lines="1"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/li_tv_training_duration"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/nr_bg"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="13sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wear listview is designed to only have 3 items to give a suitably large touch target so I wouldn't recommend trying to add more items on the screen to anything that should be interacted with.

If you purely want to have a list displayed that can be scrolled through then use a textview inside a scrollview.  You could wrapper this up into a custom widget with access methods to individual lines if you're going to re-use it a lot.

Comment: thank you, i solved the problem with the standard listview

Comment: I never thought about using a standard listview on Wear, that's a lot easier for listing information.  I'd still avoid any sort of interaction as it would be just too small a touch target.

Comment: The customer ask me, to show more than three item, so i think, that was the most optimized way. We told him, that is not a good idea, but he want it, so we do it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I modified WearableListView and made it support more than three items:

https://github.com/zjbpku/CenterScaledRecyclerView